# I constantly get killed by a command block in minecraft 1.11, how can I fix this?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I keep getting killed by a command block in minecraft 1.11, and I can't type anything, how to fix this?
I Could not find a solution for minecraft "1.11" before, but i solved it by using NBTExplorer.

Answer (score 0):

Download MCEdit: http://www.mcedit.net/downloads.html
Open the world with it, then find the command block in the world. Select it, and fill it with air to delete the block.
It's a bit overly complicated to do,but it will work for what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I don't think there is a version of worldedit for minecraft 1.11. but I found a solution, I used NBTExplorer.